# How can I convert MP4 video to MP3 audio with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to extract an MP3 audio track from an MP4 video with ffmpeg. I can do this for .flv -> mp3, but I don't know the command line parameters for mp4->mp3. For example, flv -> mp3:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -acodec copy audio.mp3
```

What parameters should I use for mp4 -> mp3?

Comment: If you don't really need an MP3, I would not convert the audio: MP4->MP3 is a lossy transformation, you will lose extra source information.

Comment: no more ffmpeg for ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @ThomWiggers is it necessarily lossy?  I don't know how mp4s are encoded, but as long as you can separate video and audio, it shouldn't have to be

Comment: The original version of this question was not clear how the audio was encoded – that got changed in edits. Remuxing does not have to be lossy.

Answer (score 311):

The basic command is:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 filename.mp3
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn music.mp3
```

Check this URL: [MP4 Video to MP3 File Using ffmpeg (Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala)](http://donnieknows.com/blog/mp4-video-mp3-file-using-ffmpeg-ubuntu-910-karmic-koala) link broken [Updated on 7th Dec 2021]

**Note:** Ubuntu does not supply FFmpeg, but the fork named [Libav](http://libav.org/). The syntax is the same – just use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg` for the above examples.

Comment: Thank you! This quality is best, or I can do better?

Comment: try with 320kbs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Bit_rate

Comment: @Louis You can still download it from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: @Louis - same for 14.10, but it is apparently returning in 15.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04

Comment: works for me `ffmpeg -i $fileNameWithExtension $fileNameOnly".mp3"`

Comment: I use Lubuntu 20_04 and avconv is not pre-installed. So I apt installed ffmpeg.

Comment: This answer would be improved if the exact command was also added on how to convert for voice quality (more compact less need for fidelity) - with a good basic voice default.

Answer (score 87):

The better way to encode MP3 is to use `-q:a` for variable bit rate.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -q:a 0 -map a out.mp3
```

The `q` option can only be used with libmp3lame and corresponds to the LAME
`-V` option. See *Encoding VBR (Variable Bit Rate) mp3 audio*:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3

Comment: @slhck ...that's a good point, but I've just tested on a video file, and leaving out `-vn` just copies the audio stream. I suppose ffmpeg must have some way of detecting the difference (I just checked a file with ffprobe, and the video was stream 1 rather than the usual 0, and had some metadata: `comment : Cover (front)`)

Comment: This one finally played also the Android Music player. Thanks

Comment: And to convert whole directory (including filenames with spaces) with the above command: 
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg  -i "$i" -q:a 0 -map a "$(basename "${i/.mp4}").mp3"; done;

Comment: How is the resulting .mp3 different from the vanilla command `ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 audio.mp3` in @Naga Harish M 's answer?   Less lossy?

Comment: @kingSlayer how do I do that on Mac?

Answer (score 20):

I got it working from youtube mp4 videos with follwing command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn audio.mp3
```

Comment: `-vn` option explicitly drops video so the conversion is much much faster.

Comment: I use this command to convert the whole folders on Windows. `FOR %I in ("*.*") DO ffmpeg -i "%I" -movflags use_metadata_tags -vn "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Music\converted\%~nI.mp3"` This will be convert mp4 to mp3 while keep metadata even some of them are missing such as `comments` field but you can recover them in **MP3tag** software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a graphical tool, such as [FFAudioConverter](https://github.com/Bleuzen/FFaudioConverter), which can be installed to Linux using Flatpak or Windows.

I tried the above and many other commands, but kept having a problem with VLC reporting incorrect and also constant changing of the length of an audio track. I did not experience this problem with FFAudioConverter.

Using the tool is very simple. Just open the application, then drag and drop a file, selected files, or a directory into the application. Verify the settings are configured for your desired output, then click Convert.

[image]

Comment: Can it take bulk? multiple videos?

Comment: @j0h Yes. From the linked GitHub description: "Convert many files or whole directories very fast".