# How to dissect a DVD into the single audio or video tracks according to the menu / chapters

Tags: audio, video, dvd

I have a Video DVD which contains audio and video tracks, which I can select and play via a menu.

So **in the DVD navigation menu**, there are

- ca. 15 **chapters**
- each of them contains 5..10 **audio tracks** and 1..5 **video tracks**.

---

EDIT:

In the meantime, I found out that for each "chapter" in the navigation, there are 2 .VOB files:

e. g. for Chapter 3:

- `VTS_03_0.VOB` seems to contain the menu for the chapter
- `VTS_03_1.VOB` contains the sequence of the audio and video tracks, but all in one file

So now it would be helpful to have kind of a table of contents which tells me that Audio track 4-3 starts at minute 5:17 of chapter 3...
Any idea, how I can get that information?

(for more background of the question, please read below)

---

On each chapter navigation "page", those audio and video tracks have or numbered e. g. "1-3 Audio" is the first audio track of chapter 3 or "4-2 Video" is the 4th video track of chapter 2...

At the moment, the only way to use this DVD is using a DVD player application together with the real DVD or an ISO image.
Instead, I want to use the content of this DVD e. g. on my smartphone.

**Question**:
So what I want to achieve is deconstructing the content of the DVD in order to

- **get 1 audio or video file** (ideally mp3 resp. mp4) **for each track** which is linked in the navigation
- and the name of the resulting audio/video file should correspond to the text used in the navigation menu, where this "track" is linked.

It would be awesome, if there was a tool which could already do this automatically and "resolve" the navigation of the DVD into those single files.

If this is not possible, I would also be highly interested in a workaround "by hand" - so e. g. if I could export the video or audio content of one chapter into one file and then somehow could export the information of the navigation menus, which would tell me: "track 2-3 audio is starting on minute 2:23 of chapter 2".., so that I then could decompose the complete chapters by hand into the chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool [makemkv](http://www.makemkv.com) can be used to read a DVD and split it out into titles with specific audio and video tracks per title in MKV format. This is effectively a lossless conversion which can be remixed into an mp4 container later.

I also think it can, at the very least, show you what chapters there are and it lists out alternate video streams. I'm not sure if you can select specific chapter sets to export.

You can then use ffmpeg to split out and transcode video and audio streams manually if required.

A basic command to [convert to mp3s with ffmpeg](http://superuser.com/questions/332347/how-can-i-convert-mp4-video-to-mp3-audio-with-ffmpeg) would then be

```
Ffmpeg -i inputFile.mkv output.mp3
```

Comment: thanks a lot! With `makemkv v1.10.7` on `MacOS X 10.11` I was able to create one `mkv`file for each track. I just head to set the minimal track length in the preferences below the default value 120 sec, because there were a lot of short audio tracks. In the makemkv window I could then browse through the list of tracks and see which filename corresponds to which chapter for roughly grouping the 175 mkv files by chapter before renaming them.

Comment: hm, after testing the single files, I had to find that there are still many tracks missing among the exported mkv files. :-( In fact, all audio files seem to be combined in one track and then there is for each audio track a very small file (< 80 kB) which does nothing, when I play it. So **I'll still have to separate the audio files in their many pieces** by hand. Now it would be helpful to have the time in _mm:ss_ where each new track starts...

Comment: Are you able to provide a smallish sample of one of your original files?

Comment: yes,sure. Which "original" file do you mean? The .VOB or the .MKV?

Comment: The .VOB would be best, but I can't really download files that are too large... 175 chapters sounds like a lot. I wonder if ffmpeg can do this in one shot straight from the VOB file.

Comment: I've uploaded one example here (35 MB, zipped) http://mabe.bplaced.net/se/chapter1_audio.zip The .VOB contains the 7 audio tracks, but the created MKV only the first track (ca. 10 seconds) - the other 6 audio tracks are missing and I am confused :-(

Comment: @MostlyHarmless Annoyingly it looks like I cannot open those files in MakeMKV to have a look at them as I'm missing the majority of the structure.  I can't see any chapter information in the MKV files you sent me either.  I know I *should* see it as a lot of my other MKV files from MakeMKV give me chapter information when I do `ffprobe -show-chapters file.mkv`.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127751/278545) suggests that Mplayer can show you chapters on a DVD.

Comment: Another alternative suggests that [DVD Decrypter](https://www.videohelp.com/software/DVD-Decrypter) can be set to split DVD files by chapter as well. https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/214957-Split-Automatically-a-DVD-to-a-lot-of-Chapter-files#post1239200